# Difference between strong interaction and weak interaction?

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics, conservation-laws, elementary-particles

I was looking at a straight forward answer on internet which I am unable to find.

Can there  be a strong interaction in which transformation of one quark flavour into other takes place(Eg. up quark -> down quark)?

Can there be a weak interaction in which transformation of quark flavors doesn't take place?

If both the answers are "No" then while checking a nuclear reaction/decay can't we just match quarks on both sides(by cancelling extra quark and anti quark pairs) and if same number of different quarks are present than it will be a strong interaction and it not than a weak interaction(provided other conservation laws are followed)?

If leptons are present in a nuclear reaction/decay does that necessarily means that the reaction is weak interaction(provided other conservation laws are followed)?

If photons are involved in a nuclear reaction does that means that it's a electromagnetic interaction?

A simple explanation with examples will be helpful.

Comment: Strong interactions preserve flavor, like neutral current weak ones. Physics texts cover that. Leptons do not interact strongly.

Comment: If you read and understand this limk your questions will be answered http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Forces/funfor.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can there be a strong interaction in which transformation of one quark flavor into another takes place (Eg. up quark → down quark)?

No. Flavor is a good quantum number.

In charged current weak interactions, flavor is violated, whence the ditty that strangeness is produced strongly (in *S=-1+1=0* associated pairs), but decays weakly: strangeness weak-decays to upness.

> Can there be a weak interaction in which transformation of quark flavors doesn't take place?

Yes, of course. [Weak neutral currents](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/neucur.html), coupling to the Z boson, do [not violate flavor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutral_current).

> If both the answers are "No", then while checking a nuclear reaction/decay can't we just match quarks on both sides(by cancelling extra quark and anti quark pairs) and if same number of different quarks are present than it will be a strong interaction and it not than a weak interaction(provided other conservation laws are followed)?

No, you saw why you can't just do that, as your premise fails. In NC neutrino scattering, flavors are conserved.

> If leptons are present in a nuclear reaction/decay does that necessarily mean that the reaction is a weak interaction?

Only for neutrinos.
The reaction won't be strong, but an electron-positron pair could be a converted photon, so EM.

> If photons are involved in a nuclear reaction does that mean that it's an electromagnetic interaction?

There could be other things happening, but certainly the photon came out of an EM coupling/vertex.